# how to fix "Failed to fill complex buffer in float converter" in EzAudio swift iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audiokit

I am using **EZaudio** to play mp3 files and it works on *iOS 12* and below but on physical Device (*iPhone X*) running *iOS 13* app crashed and console print error

> Error : Failed to fill complex buffer in float converter

I am using Audiokit and PandoraPlayer framework
what may cause this error and how to fix this ?

I'm using this code to configure `avaudiosession` and it works fine on *iOS 12* and below

```
private func configureAudio() {
        do {

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)


            updateCommandCenter()

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true;
        AKSettings.enableRouteChangeHandling = true
    }
```

I think `EZAudioFloatConverter` and microphone may cause this problem but I am not using microphone in my app

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: I kinna did but another problem showed up. Audio playaback stops on lockscreen because system cant process 4096 buffer u dont know why i set it to 4096 but still it says ints too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me: In AudioKit I changed in file `EZOutput.m`  constant : `Float64 const EZOutputDefaultSampleRate = 48000.0f`. By default this constant is `44100.0f`